# Input group with stylish checkbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a input group with stylish switch. i tried with basic bootstrap code but can't get aligned please help me with that.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">     
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
       <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

but i'm trying to have a checkbox inside the input like this

[image]

how could i do that with bootstrap. i'm using this for angularJS application
thanks

Comment: You can remove the background grey color of the .input-group-addon and remove the right border of the input field which will make it look like it's inside the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Set checkbox's CSS position to absolute and align it whit the "input-group" class